# find a substring after the last backslash with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to find the substring after the last \ in the sting (path to file, windows). 
I suppose that an elegant pythonic way should be possible (without counting "\" or writing a regression method).

```
str1 = 'qwerty\\asd\\zxc\x\\c'
str2 = 'zz\\z\\x\\c\\v\\b\\n\\m\\m2m\\m3m'
```

How to edit this line of code?

```
found_name = re.findall(r'\\(.*?)', mystr)
```

Currently it returns all after the fist back slash.

Comment: `re.findall(r'.*\\(.*)$', str1)`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require a regex, just use `split`:

```
>> str1 = 'qwerty\\asd\\zxc\x\\c'
>> str1.split(r'\\')[-1]
'c'
```

If you have to use regex for some reason then use:

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*\\(.*)$', str1)
['c']
```